# Comparing two columns in excel sheet and if match writing adjucent cell value in new cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

i have 3 columns

```
A     B     C     D
11H   3HI   xyz
2AB   2CD   dfd
3HI   11H   123
```

I am struggling for the formula through which i can compare column A & B  and if matched the adjucent cell value should be written in column D. For example

```
A     B     C     D
11H   3HI   xyz   123
2AB   2CD   dfd   ---
3HI   11H   123   xyz.
```

my column consisting of 43000 cells vertically. i have to compare all these values and write the results using excel. Please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes! its a formula error! It is out of my knowledge for writing this formula

Comment: Can anyone answer this? Badly needed!

Answer (score 1):

The formula you're after is: 
`=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)`

Here's an image.  Always show your attempts.  We tend to help those who have attempted to help themselves more.

[image]

However, if the dashes are a must instead of the #N/A in D2, then this is the formula
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$B$1:$C$3,2,FALSE),"---")`
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! ya, next time will ask u with some screen shots of my trials.